# Reduce and condense a non standard SessionWizardView

Tags: python, python-2.x, django

As I'm slowly getting the hang of Python and Django I'm becoming increasingly worried about the volume/quality of code I have. This is my first time building a Python/Django Application and I'm learning as I go.

The only section I'm really looking for help on is the below `get_context_data` of my `SessionWizardView` in **views.py** I will have to create 9 of these and I feel there is a better way of doing it. A [SessionWizardView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.SessionWizardView) is used to split a form over multiple pages for the user. [get_context_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.get_context_data) is used to return a varible to an internal page of the SessionWizardView. In the below example I have interrupted the standard SessionWizrdView pages with 9 additional internal steps (5 - 13) where the user is asked to rate a serious of images using a JS slider bar.

I included the other code elements so anyone could see what I was trying to do.

I would like to know is there a better, more condensed way of coding the below `get_context_data` of my `SessionWizardView`.

I would also like to keep it readable and easily maintainable for a beginner programmer.

**views.py**

```
class SurveyWizardOne(SessionWizardView):    

    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(SurveyWizardOne, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)                 
        if self.steps.current == '5':
            display_image = random.choice(path_one_images)                     
            context.update({'display_image': display_image}) 
            path_one_images.remove(display_image)                                                   

        elif self.steps.current == '6':
            display_image = random.choice(path_one_images)                     
            context.update({'display_image': display_image})     
            path_one_images.remove(display_image)

        elif self.steps.current == '7':
            display_image = random.choice(path_one_images)                     
            context.update({'display_image': display_image})     
            path_one_images.remove(display_image)

        elif self.steps.current == '8':
            display_image = random.choice(path_one_images)                     
            context.update({'display_image': display_image})     
            path_one_images.remove(display_image)

        elif self.steps.current == '9':
            display_image = random.choice(path_one_images)                     
            context.update({'display_image': display_image})     
            path_one_images.remove(display_image)

        elif self.steps.current == '10':
            display_image = random.choice(path_one_images)                     
            context.update({'display_image': display_image})     
            path_one_images.remove(display_image)

        elif self.steps.current == '11':
            display_image = random.choice(path_one_images)                     
            context.update({'display_image': display_image})     
            path_one_images.remove(display_image)

        elif self.steps.current == '12':
            display_image = random.choice(path_one_images)                     
            context.update({'display_image': display_image})     
            path_one_images.remove(display_image)

        elif self.steps.current == '13':
            display_image = random.choice(path_one_images)                     
            context.update({'display_image': display_image})     
            path_one_images.remove(display_image)

        return context

def done(self, form_list, **kwargs): 
    global SurveyWizardOneCounter
    global TotalMaxCounter
    SurveyWizardOneCounter += 1   
    TotalMaxCounter += 1    
    return render_to_response('Return_to_AMT.html', {
        'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],            
    })
```

**wizard_form.html**

Ive included thsi for the big picture, Im not too worried about my wizard form as I just have the below for each of the steps. It dosent require much if any mainteance.

```
    {% if wizard.steps.current == '5' %}                    
            <img src="{% static "survey/images/pathone/" %}{{display_image}}" height="600" width="500" style="border:1px solid black;" align="middle"/>                                                                     
            <section>   
                <span class="tooltip"></span>   
                <div id="slider"></div>  
                <span class="volume"></span>  
            </section>      
    {% endif %}
```

**forms.py**

I have also just included this for the big picture, Its jsut a hidden field necessary for each step of the SurveyWizardView.

```
class SurveyFormF1(forms.Form):      
    nothing = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)

class SurveyFormF2(forms.Form):        
    nothing = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)    

...
...
```

Comment: Why 13 different `ifs` if the code executed is the same? Is this the real code?

Comment: yes it is the real code, The `if` are for each step e.g. elif self.steps.current == '9':

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something but your `get_context_data` can be simplified to:

```
def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
    context = super(SurveyWizardOne, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)                 
    if self.steps.current in ['5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13']:
        display_image = random.choice(path_one_images)                     
        context.update({'display_image': display_image})     
        path_one_images.remove(display_image)
    return context
```

Note also that the list of numbers can be written as `map(str,range(5,13+1))` or you could check `5 <= int(self.steps.current) <= 13`.

Comment: That works, Ive never used the `if` `in` `list` functionality before. thanks